# The proper use of articles (a/the) with physical concepts

Tags: discussion, language

I'm not a native speaker and I have this question for some time now. What articles and when should be placed with physical and mathematical concepts? General Rules?

- a/the force
- a/the manifold
- a/the flux of a/the/() field
- ...

I think it would be better to ask here rahther than on english.stackexchange.com because I believe here people know all the variants and cases of using the terminology.

Comment: Interesting use of the meta site :-) This isn't really about the main site, so I'm not sure whether it belongs here, but I would feel bad closing it.

Comment: This question(v1) belongs on English.SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, this could go on english.SE imo, but the big users there are pretty ardently against questions from non-native speakers these days. They don't want to clutter their site with lowbrow questions from people not tenured in the humanities. (Okay end of rant, I promise.)

---

The thing is, articles in English are very context dependent, and there are very few terms that are consistently preceded by one form or another. The definite article *the* comes before any nouns somehow uniquely defined by the situation:

> The force in this particular case...

while the indefinite article *a/an* precedes nouns that are particular instances where more variety can be imagined:

> There is probably an electromagnetic field of some sort worth considering...

Used properly, articles can very well distinguish between unspecified instances of abstract notions and specific, well-defined examples of those notions:

> While a manifold is just a topological space locally homeomorphic to R^n, the manifold we will consider is the unique one-dimensional, compact, connected manifold without boundary (i.e. the circle).

There really aren't any better general rules, even for specific things in physics. (Sorry - I've heard English is one of the hardest languages to learn and master, and even as a native speaker I believe it.) That said, on the internet even native speakers (myself included) slip up in more egregious ways than using the wrong article, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: I am a big user on ELU, I am not a native speaker, and I have actually [answered](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/) a very similar question there myself. Your rant amounts to saying that the big users on Physics are pretty ardently against questions from bus drivers these days.

Comment: http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/

Comment: English.SE is an experts site like Physics.SE, and has similar guidelines for question quality. But where Physics typically gets questions like "Can the vibrational energy of a engine be used to increase efficiency?", English gets a much larger share of questions which are analogous to "My car shake why?".